# Changing address bar via htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

I want to change my address bar via htaccess.
My link is: `http://englishforyou.ir/index.php?content=about`
And I want to change it to `http://englishforyou.ir/content/about`.
My htaccess code is:

```
RewriteEngine on <br>
RewriteRule ^content/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ index.php?content=$1 [NC]
```

But it doesn't work. You can test it here: [englishforyou.ir](http://englishforyou.ir)

My index file is:

```
<?php
require_once 'includes/function.php';
?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
 <head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <title>Untitled Document</title>
 </head>
 <body>
   <div>
     test
     <a href="index.php?content=about" class="drop">About me</a>
   </div>
   <?php loadContent('content', 'mainpage'); ?>
 </body>
</html>
```

My function file is:

```
function loadContent($where, $default='') {
  // Get the content from the url 
  // Sanitize it for security reasons
  $content = filter_input(INPUT_GET, $where, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
  $default = filter_var($default, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
  // If there wasn't anything on the url, then use the default
  $content = (empty($content)) ? $default : $content;
  // If you found have content, then get it and pass it back
  if ($content) {
    // sanitize the data to prevent hacking.
    $html = include $content.'.php';
    return $html;
  }
}
```

And my about me file is:

```
<div>
  <h4>
    This page is about me.
   <a href="index.php?content=mainpage" class="drop">home</a>
  </h4>
</div>
```

Comment: It is working actually, try to refresh your browser without cache.

Answer (score 2):

Your .htaccess file is right and it is working.

You might have to refresh your browser without cache, or wait for it to refresh by itself.

If you are using Firefox or Chrome, use `Ctrl+F5` to refresh overriding the cache.

**Note:** You just have to use the url `http://englishforyou.ir/content/about` instead of `http://englishforyou.ir/index.php?content=about`

**EDIT**

Add this line to your .htaccess to redirect  from `http://englishforyou.ir/index.php?content=about` to `http://englishforyou.ir/content/about`

```
RewriteRule ^index\.php\?content\=(.*)$ /content/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: That's not what that rewrite rule is for. The rule you use works if you go to /content/about, leaves the address bar the same, and internally rewrites it to /index.php?content=about - changing the address bar should be `Redirect 301 /index.php?content=about http://englishforyou.ir/content/about` - but since you're just starting your page, you should just link to the clean/rewritten URLs

Comment: Sorry, but I think that the htaccess code is going to change http://englishforyou.ir/index.php?content=about to  englishforyou.ir/content/about. Could you please explain a little more?

Comment: If you want "If I enter englishforyou.ir/index.php?content=about, go to englishforyou.ir/content/about", you want a _redirect_, not a rewrite. A redirect sends the browser to a different URL (that is, it changes the address bar). You started with a _rewrite_, not a redirect, that says "If I enter englishforyou.ir/content/about, display the page as if I entered englishforyou.ir/index.php?content=about,but keep displaying the clean URL englishforyou.ir/content/about in the address bar".

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.* - [L]
RewriteRule ^system/([^/]*)\.html$ system.php?route=$1
```

This translates the url `http://www.domain.com/system/home.html` to `http://www.domain.com/system.php?route=home`
And make sure you are allowed to use .htaccess

Comment: Why should the OP "try this"? A good answer will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done that way, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.